# Classic ASP export to CSV generates blank 1st row

Tags: csv, asp-classic, export-to-csv

I have a .asp page which generates a csv file to download using the data from a mysql database. My issue is, the first row of the generated csv file is blank.  How do I eliminate the blank 1st row from the output?

```
<%Response.Buffer = True
Response.Clear
Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=export.csv"
struserid=Request.QueryString("uid")
set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
%>
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="databaseconnection.asp"-->
<%Con.open DSNtest
set rec1=con.execute ("SELECT * FROM orders where receivedp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND pid = '" & struserid & "' order by zipid asc")%>
sep=;
Address;City;State;Zip;
<%while not rec1.eof
strzipid = rec1("zipid")
set rec3=con.execute ("SELECT * FROM zip where zipcode = '" & strzipid & "'")
%>
<%=rec1("address")%>;<%=rec3("city")%>;<%=rec3("state")%>;<%=rec3("zipcode")%>;
<%rec1.movenext
wend
rec1.close
set rec1 = nothing
rec3.close
set rec3 = nothing
con.close
set con = Nothing%>
```

Comment: Why make nested repetative database calls when you can make one database call? `SELECT * from orders AS o INNER JOIN zip AS z ON o.zipid = z.zipcode WHERE o.receivedp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND o.pid = '" & struserid & "' order by o.zipid asc`. Read up on JOINS: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a guess here, but try having your vbs in a single block of code and use vbcrlf to add line breaks where you need them - ie

```
<% Con.open DSNtest
set rec1=con.execute ("SELECT * FROM orders where receivedp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND pid = '" & struserid & "' order by zipid asc")
Response.write "sep=;" & vbcrlf
Response.write "Address;City;State;Zip;" & vbcrlf
while not rec1.eof
strzipid = rec1("zipid")
set rec3=con.execute ("SELECT * FROM zip where zipcode = '" & strzipid & "'")
Response.write rec1("address")&";"&rec3("city")&";"&rec3("state")&";"&rec3("zipcode") & vbcrlf
rec1.movenext
wend
'etc
```

Closing a block of asp code and starting a new one on the next line adds an extra line